# Make the articles list in three columns

Tags: html, css

I wonder if there is the way to create css-rules to display the articles in three columns as shown (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRSGs.png). Preferred HTML markup is:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
...
<div>6</div>
```

The only condition is to avoid additional manipulations with html-markup during the render - no nested blocks and so on. Any ideas?

Please see the code at JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/3nv7rkcg](http://jsfiddle.net/3nv7rkcg)

Comment: What is how elements are stacked by default. What's the problem? Do you mean no spacing bottom and top?

Comment: nope, by default there will be the clearer under every line of elements. i need the elements to be aligned by columns.

Comment: please see the code and result http://jsfiddle.net/3nv7rkcg/

Comment: I think without additional divs for each column there is no pure css solution.

Comment: [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is the usual answer to this often asked question.

Comment: Looks like Masonry.js is like Isotope without the sorting part. If you want some sorting use Isotope if not use Masonry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very difficult to make from css and it can't be dynamic. So please better to use js http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ .

**Now we can make it from css too :)**

Here is the code

```css
@import "compass/css3";

*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


article {
 -moz-column-width: 13em;
 -webkit-column-width: 13em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em; 
  
}

section {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:  0.25rem;
 padding:  1rem;
 width:  100%; 
 background:  #efefef;
}


p {
 margin:  1rem 0; 
}




/*  styles for background color, etc; not necessary for this thing to work  */



body {
 padding:  1em;
 font-family:  "Garamond", serif; 
}




h1 {
  font-size:  3rem;
  font-weight:  800;
}

body {
  line-height:  1.25;
}


p {
 text-align:  left;
}
```

```html
<article>

  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error aliquid reprehenderit expedita odio beatae est.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis quaerat suscipit ad.</p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nihil alias amet dolores fuga totam sequi a cupiditate ipsa voluptas id facilis nobis.</p>
  </section>


  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem ut debitis dolorum earum expedita eveniet voluptatem quibusdam facere eos numquam commodi ad iusto laboriosam rerum aliquam.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat  architecto quis tenetur fugiat veniam iste molestiae fuga labore!</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit accusamus tempore at porro officia rerum est impedit ea ipsa tenetur. Labore libero hic error sunt laborum expedita.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima asperiores eveniet vero velit eligendi aliquid in.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus dolorem maxime minima animi cum.</p>
  </section>
  
</article>
```

Comment: Isotope is easy to use and it looks fantastic!

Comment: Sure, we have another option make from js